# Can't immplement OnNavigatedTo when AppMapViewModelBase already used

Tags: xamarin, parameters, prism

I'm trying to pass a parameter from pageA to pageB  using prism 
,my project is PCL
pageB is CarouselPage page
prism created a viewModel from pageB using AppMapViewModelBase as the following

public class ViewSpotMainViewModel : AppMapViewModelBase,  IActiveAware

I tried to add INavigationAware but It did't ask to implement the mothods.
later I found that the methods OnNavigatedTo() and OnNavigatedFrom is a part of  AppMapViewModelBase
my Question is how I can get the parameters on a viewModel that using AppMapViewModelBase interface ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply override their implementation.

Comment: Hi Brian ... that was what I did , but still not getting the method triggered  public override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
        {
            base.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);
            Debug.WriteLine("Not working ...");

        } 
I tried this at the Main CarouselPage viewController and even on each child ....

Comment: Changing pages in a Carousel Page is not navigation. So it won't work for those child pages.

Comment: thanks Brian ..
I will change the design from Contentpage=>Carousel to  Contentpage=>Contentpage to keep going on ..
i would appreciate if you could find some time to check that parameters are passing from Contentpage page calling Carousel one on a project built with Ultimate UI for Xamarin (https://www.infragistics.com/products/xamarin)

Comment: The same code works after reinstalling Visual Studio .